# How to set HighCharts x-axis value

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I want to use HighCharts to show plot graph, 
and `x-axis` value can be corresponded to the data value of `x`
but I don't know how to do this 
ex:
I have data

```
[[201111, 10], [201112, 20], [201301, 50]]
```

and make the x-axis value just the data value of x 
so the x-axis value can be 
    201111, 201112, 201301 
the plot graph has 3 plots

```
(201111, 10), (201112, 20), (201301, 50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tickPositions` and return there array of xAxis.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yuw42h6e/

Comment: but the interval is not same, I'd like to make the interval of x axis value keep same like this: 201111----201112----201301 , is it possible by using HighCharts?

Comment: Only in the highstock, when you use datetime type of chart. Then you need to use [ordinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) param.